# add one button in shopify site header using shopify app in ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, shopify, shopify-app

I need to insert one **button** after search icon in shopify sites throgh the shopify app.Give me some suggestions.

[image: Like this image]

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: `<%= button_to "Button Text", some_path %>`

Comment: I am not asking about rails button tag.I need to inject one button in shopify site frontend.Installing my shopify app needs to be trigger the above action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully you should replace/overwrite your snippets/header.liquid file in your store's theme with the help of Shopify API as below:

In your app, try the below in your root function as:

```
header = ShopifyAPI::Asset.find("sections/header.liquid")
header.value # returns the contents of the header.liquid
```

update your `header.value` using rails sub! as:

```
#this will add the button at appropriate place instead `{% endif %}`
header.value.sub!("{% endif %}", "<button type='button'>Click Button</button> {% endif %}") 

#do save    
header.save
```

Hope this will help you!!